# How to call same function in jquery for two checkbox events?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Triggering jquery event function at page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765542/triggering-jquery-event-function-at-page-load)

I have a function to do something when a checkbox in a checkbox group is clicked to be checked. But now, I want something more. When the page is first time loaded, I have couple of the checkboxes pre-checked, so I want the function can be called for those checked checkbox, then, when user click checkbox, the same function will run again.

I tried `.bind("ready, click",function())`... doesn't work.

here is the current code which is working fine for click event, thanks!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.list_item').click(function(e){
        var facility_id = $(this).val();

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                do somthing 1;
                    }
            });
            } else {
                do somthing 2;
                }
            }           
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Just simulate a click by calling `.click()` after you bound the event handler. In case this actually changes the state of the checkboxes, you can use `triggerHandler`: http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/

Comment: Apparently `triggerHandler` handler works a bit differently than other jQuery methods, so using a separate function, as suggested by the answers in the other questions, might actually be easier in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: using `.each` when DOM loads API = http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Further you can refactor like this: move `.is(:checked)` in seperate function and call it from click function.

The reason click work is because the `click` event is well bound to the element. but when you load `.each` will be the right API to use.

hope this helps, please let me know if I missed anything.

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.list_item').each(function(e){
        var facility_id = $(this).val();

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                do somthing 1;
                    }
            });
            } else {
                do somthing 2;
                }
            }           
        });
    })
```

Comment: You could just do `$('.list_item').click()`. Now there's no click handler.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Hiya bruv, howz you? +1 **or** do this `$('.list_item').trigger('click')` indeed OP please note, I am not sure the complexity involved with click with in DOM in specific case, i.e. Validation is there or something, `:)` Thanks for comment though bruv

Comment: Validation or not, *there's no click handler at all in your example*. And calling the click handler (`$.triggerHandler()` as @Felix points out for certain cases) is more appropriate; call what it has already. Specificity of handlers can be used by adding and calling event namespaces.

Comment: @JaredFarrish OPs code already works for click, Hence I only provided the solution where the problem lies, Although I have recommend that s/he can move the common code in sperate function and use accordingly  in both events, please let me know if I am wrong, `:)`

Comment: wa.. thanks, .each works good! I still don't understand how to combine two events into one function..

Comment: also.... turns out these two events will need two slight different behavior, so I am using two functions anyway

Comment: Cool BINGO @user1487327 if you have different behaviour then use `.each` for one beahviour and `.click` for another `:)` let me know how it goes man!